# Oracle Between Operator for Character Values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, character, between

I have the following Table which has `sequence number` and `Station codes`. I want to bring list of stations between two stations.

If i do

```
select Station Code 
from Table1 
where Station Code BETWEEN 'BWI' and 'PHL'
```

It should give me stations based on the sequence like this -> (BWI,BAL,WIL,PHL).

Whereas it is giving my the following stations -> (BWI,PHL,NWK,NYP).

Please let me know who do i bring the desired values? I have added the sample Data in Table1 below.

Table1

```
Sequence Number Station Code
    1           WAS
    2           BWI
    3           BAL
    4           WIL
    5           PHL
    6           NWK
    7           NYP
```

Comment: i added Table one in table form i dont know why it came as a line. I hope you guys understand that its a two column table with 7 rows of Data

Comment: I just edit for you :). You need add 4 spaces before each line to show in code format

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the ordering of the stations, you can use:

```
select t1.Code 
from Table1 t1 cross join
     (select min(number) as minn, max(number) maxn
      from table1
      where code in ('BWI' and 'PHL')
     tt
where t1.number between minn and maxnn;
```

Comment: Thank you all , I was able to get the required result based on the solution you guys have proposed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
'BWI' and 'PHL'
```

is returning all rows where code is between those as string comparasion.

You want

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Sequence Number 
    between (SELECT Sequence Number FROM Table1 WHERE Station Code ='BAL')
    and (SELECT Sequence Number FROM Table1 WHERE Station Code ='PHL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's tagged with Oracle, here's an Oracle solution which does not need multiple table scans:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87b43/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( Sequence_Number, Station_Code ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'WAS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'BWI' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'BAL' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'WIL' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'PHL' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'NWK' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'NYP' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
START WITH Station_Code = 'BWI'
CONNECT BY PRIOR Sequence_Number  = Sequence_Number - 1
AND        PRIOR Station_Code <> 'PHL'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87b43/6/0)**:

```
| SEQUENCE_NUMBER | STATION_CODE |
|-----------------|--------------|
|               2 |          BWI |
|               3 |          BAL |
|               4 |          WIL |
|               5 |          PHL |
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from table1

where sequence between

(select sequence_number from table where station code= 'BWI')

and

(select sequence_number from table where station code= 'PHL');